# Избавиться от QSignalMapper

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, g-signal-connect

Мне нужно что бы несколько объектов вызывали один слот, и можно было понять, какой объект вызвал слот. В данном примере я попробовал использовать `QSignalMapper`. Но он работает только со строками и с числами. Объекты у меня не получилось передать. И тк `QSignalMapper` отмечен как `QT_DEPRECATED`, хочу от него избавиться.

[image: Приложение]

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QSignalMapper>
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

public slots:
    void le(const QString &num);
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QSignalMapper *signalMapper;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget),
    signalMapper(new QSignalMapper(this))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lineEdit_1->setPlaceholderText("#1");
    ui->lineEdit_2->setPlaceholderText("#2");
    ui->lineEdit_3->setPlaceholderText("#3");

    connect(ui->lineEdit_1, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, signalMapper, QOverload<>::of(&QSignalMapper::map));
    signalMapper->setMapping(ui->lineEdit_1, ui->lineEdit_1);
    connect(ui->lineEdit_2, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, signalMapper, QOverload<>::of(&QSignalMapper::map));
    signalMapper->setMapping(ui->lineEdit_2, ui->lineEdit_2);
    connect(ui->lineEdit_3, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, signalMapper, QOverload<>::of(&QSignalMapper::map));
    signalMapper->setMapping(ui->lineEdit_3, ui->lineEdit_3);

    connect(signalMapper, QOverload<QObject *>::of(&QSignalMapper::mapped), this, &Widget::le);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete signalMapper;
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::le(QObject *num)
{
    QLineEdit *le = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit*>(num);
    if (le) {
        le->setReadOnly(true);
        ui->textBrowser->append(le->text());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оказывается "*Qt предоставляет функцию Qobject::sender(), которая возвращает указатель на объект, пославший сигнал.*"

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QSignalMapper>
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

public slots:
    void lele();
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QDebug>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lineEdit_1->setPlaceholderText("#1");
    ui->lineEdit_2->setPlaceholderText("#2");
    ui->lineEdit_3->setPlaceholderText("#3");

    connect(ui->lineEdit_1, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, this, &Widget::lele);
    connect(ui->lineEdit_2, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, this, &Widget::lele);
    connect(ui->lineEdit_3, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, this, &Widget::lele);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::lele()
{
    QLineEdit *le = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit *>(sender());
    if (le) {
        ui->textBrowser->append(le->text());
        le->setReadOnly(true);
    } else {
        ui->textBrowser->append("false");
    }
}
```